# Как определить последовательность месяцев?

Tags: delphi

У меня есть программа, которую я пишу на дельфи... в ней текущее число, месяц и год, получаются в результате выполнения функции и выбираются отдельно. Задача в том, что мне надо сделать отчет за какой то период, но, я не пойму, как определить последовательность месяцев... т.е. как сделать, что бы, к примеру, если задан временной промежуток с января по апрель, то программа после января понимала, что сначала надо перейти на февраль, потом на март, потом на апрель... вот такой вопрос!извините за некоторую витиеватость в нем!))))

Answer (score 1):

Если нужны конкретные даты - используйте IncMonth() и иже с ними
Если просто месяцы, то я думаю, и без массивов с февраля по июнь это будет for i:=2 to 5 do 
+- единица

Answer (score 0):

Вспомогательный массив. Где индексы - месцы, значения - индексы.

Answer (score 0):

Нумеровать месяцы с нуля. Номер месяца - остаток от деления на 12.

Answer (score 0):

Назначить совой тип данных с месяцами... Они будут идти  впорядке возростания...